# What exactly does this piece of code do?

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer,

I have an array called myArray and was wanting to know what exactly the if statment in this code does. Also what does myArray[count] do?

```
         for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)

            if (number == myArray[i])
            {
            containsNumber = true;
            }

            if ( !containsNumber )
            {
               myArray [ count ] = number;
               count++;
            } // end if
```

Cheers

Comment: What is your debugger telling ?

Comment: myArray[count] is referencing myArray at index 'count' whatever the value of 'count' is at that time. You didn't include enough information to know what count is because its declaration is not present.

Comment: You need a good Java book. Even if someone explains it here, chances are you are going to see more java terms/concepts which you may not be familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notice**

Because the code is not complete I have to do some assumptions:

- All variables are declared and initalized before
- `count` represents the number of elements in the array
- The array is sufficiently sized
- `containsNumber` is initalized with `false`

### Short

It checks if the given number exists in the array and if not it will add it.

### Explained

At first, to make it a bit more readable we can add two braces after the for instruction:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (number == myArray[i])
    {
        containsNumber = true;
    }
}

if ( !containsNumber )
{
   myArray [ count ] = number;
   count++;
} // end if
```

Because there are no breaces after the `for` it will just affect the following statement or block, which is the `if` statement.

At first the code will loop through the array and check every position smaller than `count` (value of `i` ) for the given number.

If the value is found (`if (number == myArray[i])`) the variable `containsNumber` is set to `true`.

After iterating over the array the variable `containsNumber` is checked.

An `if` statement must contain a boolean value, so you can just write `if (containsNumber)` instead of `if (containsNumber == true)`.

The `!` negates the boolean value. That means you check if `containsNumber` is not true. `if (containsNumber != true)` or `if (containsNumber == false)` would be the same.

If the number is not in the array (`containsNumber` is `false`) than it is added at the next position (`myArray [ count ] = number;`) and `count` is incremented by one (`count++;`).

### Example

Let's say the array contains the values `1`, `5` and `7`.
Number has the value `4` and count is `3` because the array contains `3` elements.

**For loop:**

**First iteration**

`i` has the value `0` --> `0` is smaller than `3` (`count`)

`if (number == myArray[i])` --> `if (4 == myArray[0])` --> `if (4 == 1)`

--> `false`

**Second iteration**

`i` has the value `1` --> `1` is smaller than `3` (`count`)

`if (number == myArray[i])` --> `if (4 == myArray[1])` --> `if (4 == 5)`

--> `false`

**Third iteration**

`i` has the value `2` --> `2` is smaller than `3` (`count`)

`if (number == myArray[i])` --> `if (4 == myArray[2])` --> `if (4 == 7)`

--> `false`

**Fourth iteration**

`i` has the value `3` --> `3` is not smaller than `3` (`count`)

`for` ends

**Next step**

`containsNumber` is still `false`

`if ( !containsNumber )` --> the value of `containsNumber` is negated what means `if (true)`

`myArray [ count ] = number;` --> `myArray [ 3 ] = 4;`

The value of `number` (`4`) is set to the fourth position of the array (remember, the array starts with `0`).

Now the array contains the values `1`, `5`, `7` and `4`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's searching for a value. If it exists, skip. If it doesn't, add it in. Here's the pseudocode:

```
for i = 0 to the value in count
    if number is equal to myArray at position i
        Set a flag to say the number has been found.

    if(the flag is not set, the number has not been found)
        Set myArray at position count to the number i'm searching for
        increase count.
```

Comment: it should be noted that this would only work with an array with a greater size than it has values, otherwise you'll end up with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: It appears so, unless the author was happy to overwrite the last parts of the array. Without overwriting, it seems to me it would need at most twice the amount of space, assuming `count` begins at the last index of the array.

Comment: +1 for the pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

if the "number" is not in the  "myArray" Array the number would assign to the array on the current position (count).

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement

```
if (number == myArray[i])
```

checks if the item at position `i` in the `myArray` is equal to the value that the variable `number` contains

The second if statement

```
if ( !containsNumber )
```

Checks if the value of the variable `containsNumber` is false. If it is, it probably means that the array doesn't contain the number

In this case, `myArray [ count ] = number;` set the item at position `count` of the array to the `number` that you were previously searching, so that now the array contains also this value

Answer (score 0):

There are two `if` statements, which one do you mean?

```
if (number == myArray[i])
```

If `number` is equal to element `i` in `myArray`.

```
if ( !containsNumber )
```

If `containsNumber` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It will check the `number` in `myArray`. If `myArray` didn't contain `number` then it will store the number at last index of `myArray` specified by `count` and increment `count` by 1.

Answer (score 0):

The first IF statement

```
if (number == myArray[i])
```

checks if the number is there in myArray. If not then it adds the number at the current index position & increments the count.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code that you put only checks if the value 'number' exist in the array 'myArray'. Then, an IF condition checks if the variable containsNumber and increases the limit 'count' used in the FOR. But this IF condition is not part of the FOR, it is outside.

Probably it lacks of curly brackets to delimitate the FOR.

This is what is interpreted by the machine:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  if (number == myArray[i])
  {
     containsNumber = true;
  }

if ( !containsNumber )
{
   myArray [ count ] = number;
   count++;
 } // end if
```